# How to get details about a publication using Microsoft Academic Knowledge API

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'm using the Interpret and Evaluate methods from [Project Academic Knowledge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/academic-services/project-academic-knowledge/introduction).
If you search for `Composite(J.JN='jama')` and include `J.JId` in the request, you'll get a response with the Id `172573765`:

```
{
    "logprob": -14.823,
    "prob": 3.651345212E-07,
    "Id": 2107832644,
    "J": {
      "JId": 172573765
     }
}
```

You can find more details about that journal by opening: https://academic.microsoft.com/journal/172573765

However, there doesn't seem to be a way to retrieve that same information (Number of papers, number of citations, website, about) using the API. How can we get this (other than by accessing the URL of the journal)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project Academic Knowledge allows you to retrieve [journal entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/academic-services/project-academic-knowledge/reference-journal-entity-attributes) using the Evaluate method. The query is simply Id=JId. For example, to retrieve the journal name, publication and citation counts you'd use:
https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate?subscription-key=SUBSCRIPTION_KEY&attributes=Id,JN,DJN,CC,PC&expr=Id=172573765

See the [journal entity documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/academic-services/project-academic-knowledge/reference-journal-entity-attributes) page for a list of the available attributes you can request.

Comment: Thanks, that does work partially. But still some fields are not available in the journal entity:
About
Website Links
Related Journals
Related Topics Any idea how to get those in?

Comment: If the attributes aren't listed then you'd need to make a feature request to have them added to the API using the "feedback" link on [Microsoft Academic](https://academic.microsoft.com).